# MongoDB - Post and Get hedging

Tags: security, mongodb, post, get

is it enough to use string to coverage the $_POST['xxx'] and $_GET['xxx'] inputs?

for example
$_POST['xxx'] = (string)$_POST['xxx'];

Comment: `$_POST['xxx']` will be a string, so casting it again won't do anything.

Comment: @Blender: posting `xxx[]=1&xxx[]=2` will result in `is_array($_POST['xxx']) === true`.